# Stationarity of harmonic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, stationary-processes

I have to find out wether $$ X_t = \sum_{k=1}^{L} c_k \sin(2\pi v_k t + \phi_k) , t\in \mathbb{R} $$ is a stationary process, where $\phi_1 \ldots \phi_L$ are independent and uniformly distributed in $[-\pi, \pi]$. Also, $c_k$ and $v_k$ are constants.

Yet, I am stuck and can't find out from where to start. I know that:

$$ E(X_t) = \sum_{k=1}^{L} c_k E\left( \sin(2\pi v_k t + \phi_k)\right) $$

Now for every $k \in \{1,2 \ldots k \}$:

$$ E(\sin(2\pi v_k t+ \phi_k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(2\pi v_k t + \phi_k) d\phi_k =0$$

Since $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(u)du = 0 $, because the sine an even function. So  the mean is constant for this particular process. I evaluated it and found that the variance is also constant.

For the autocovariance function:

$$ \gamma(h) = E(X_t X_{t+h}) = \sum_k \sum_j c_k c_j E(\sin(2\pi v_k t + \phi_k) \sin(2\pi v_j + \phi_j)) $$

And I know the expected value must have something to do with the ortogonality of sines and cosines. Yet I am stuck. Can you guys give me any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi_k$ has a uniform distribution on $[-\pi,\pi]$, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sin\left(2\pi v_kt+\phi_k\right)\right]=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin\left(2\pi v_kt+u\right) \mathrm du. 
$$
This is not much harder to compute than $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin\left( u\right) \mathrm du$; in both cases, a primitive can be found.

For the covariance, let 
$$
a_{k,j}:= \mathbb E\left[\sin\left(2\pi v_kt+\phi_k\right)\sin\left(2\pi v_j(t+h)+\phi_j\right)\right].
$$
When $k=j$, this reduced to a similar computation as before. 
When $k\neq j$, the random variable involved in the expectation are independent.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added an edit to my question :)

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!